# How to add a int and a str to print out after it calculates the numbers? I keep trying and it doesnt work?

Tags: python, calculator

Im still VERY NEW to programming and python...Any help would be GREATLY appreciated..

I am doing a BMI calculator in my python class.. I actually got it working the way the instructor wanted but I wanted to just improve it slightly and I had no idea it was going to be this difficult.
My original code that actually worked as the intructor wanted is this:

```
height = input("enter your height in m: ")
weight = input("enter your weight in kg: ")
height = float(height)
weight = int(weight)
result = (height ** 2)
 
print(int(weight / result))
```

Now when it runs it prints out Enter your height in m:
Then you enter the height then it prints
enter your weight in kg:
then you enter your weight then it just calculates it and returns just the resulting number.. In this case 35.

I wanted to be a little ambitious and I wanted to make it print out like this:
I wanted it to print
Your BMI is 35  instead of just 35..
I wouldnt have thought it would be that hard but WOW..
I have tried SO MANY different ways..
Here is the last I tried.. And it actually prints the way I want it to but then it shows this big LONG error.. It even calculates it correctly.. So I dont know why its giving the error when its performing what I want it to do???
Here is the code I have in it now...

```
height = input("enter your height in m: ")
weight = input("enter your weight in kg: ")

height = float(height)
weight = int(weight)
result= (height ** 2)
BMI = int(weight / result)
print("Your BMI is: ")
print(BMI)
```

Now it finishes calculating.. And it prints out Your BMI is 35      I am putting in 1.6 for height and 90 for kg

But then after it prints it out as I want it to I see this..

```
enter your height in m: 1.6
enter your weight in kg: 90
Your BMI is 
35



.
.
.
Checking if you are printing a single number: 
 The BMI as an integer (using meters and kilograms)...
Running some tests on your code:
.
.
.
FFF
======================================================================
FAIL: test_1 (__main__.MyTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 70, in test_1
    self.run_test(given_answer=['2', '8'], expected_print='2\n')
  File "main.py", line 67, in run_test
    self.assertEqual(fake_out.getvalue(), expected_print)
AssertionError: 'Your BMI is \n2\n' != '2\n'
- Your BMI is 
  2


======================================================================
FAIL: test_2 (__main__.MyTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 73, in test_2
    self.run_test(given_answer=['1.8', '85'], expected_print='26\n')
  File "main.py", line 67, in run_test
    self.assertEqual(fake_out.getvalue(), expected_print)
AssertionError: 'Your BMI is \n26\n' != '26\n'
- Your BMI is 
  26


======================================================================
FAIL: test_3 (__main__.MyTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 76, in test_3
    self.run_test(given_answer=['1.6', '90'], expected_print='35\n')
  File "main.py", line 67, in run_test
    self.assertEqual(fake_out.getvalue(), expected_print)
AssertionError: 'Your BMI is \n35\n' != '35\n'
- Your BMI is 
  35


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.004s

FAILED (failures=3)
 
KeyboardInterrupt

```

I have NO IDEA what this means or why its doing it when its calculating it correctly and printing it out correctly????
PLEASE HELP???

Comment: Seems like a homework problem so I won't provide a complete solution. Just a hint: You need to read the question more carefully and check the format of input and output.

Comment: You are not providing the full code, since in the Traceback an AssertionError is raised, but in the shown code no assertion is found.

Comment: well apparently its too long to put all of it in this.. It cut some of it off. I did copy the whole thing and pasted it but it cut some of it off.. I didnt notice that until now.. If I could just send a screenshot of it I would but I dont see where to attach one here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's good that you are providing more information to the user than just printing out the BMI. But in this case, your test wants only a single number as output for validation.

Your code is correct but.
A few improvements which you can make in your code:

```
height = input("enter your height in m: ")
weight = input("enter your weight in kg: ")

height = float(height)
weight = int(weight)
result= (height ** 2)
BMI = int(weight / result)
print("Your BMI is: ")
print(BMI)
```

to:

```
height = input("enter your height in m: ")
weight = int(input("enter your weight in kg: "))#Ask user input in `int` form only.

height = float(height)
result= (height ** 2)
BMI = int(weight / result)
#print("Your BMI is: ") Your evaluator(which checks the code) want the output i.e. BMI only. Kindly remove this and it will work
print(BMI)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use `f-string` formatting:

```
print(f"Your BMI is: {BMI}")
```

I would suggest to read [`this`](https://towardsdatascience.com/introducing-f-strings-the-best-option-for-string-formatting-in-python-b52975b47b84), notice that the `f-string` formatting is considered the best practice.

---

To make your output `int`, I would suggest to use the `round` built-in function:

```
BMI = round(weight / result)
```

Answer (score 0):

the testing you are using wants your print to be only the BMI calculated, so the last print should only be

```
print(BMI)
```

or you could try:

```
print("Your BMI is: ", BMI)
```

Comment: I had already tried that.. It still gives that error after it prints it..

Answer (score 0):

I will not focus on the test's error messages but more on what you are trying to achieve.

Python is a "typed" language, meaning that numbers and strings will be considered differently by Python and with some limitations.

I am providing two possible solutions (working with Python 3.9 but you might experience a different behavior, depending of your Python version):

```
print("Your BMI is:", int(weight / result))
print(f"Your BMI is: {int(weight / result)}")
```

- the first one is using a comma to tell Python that there are two elements to be displayed (the "Your BMI is:" string first and then the result of the calculation).
- the second one is using the f-string method that allows you to include variable or more complex calculations/formulas within a string, using {}.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit on the border between an answer and a comment; you're not asking your question correctly, but explaining what's wrong with how you're asking your question (which normally belongs in a comment) will probably get you most of the way, if not all the way, to understanding the problem. It appears that your professor has set up assertion tests, which is something you can do in Python to raise an error if the output is not what's "expected". This is useful for professors as they can basically make your program "fail" if you don't write it correctly and give the "correct" answer to the question. Your question is not complete because, while these assertion tests are not part of the code that you submitted to your professor, they *are* part of what's being run, and so you should have included that as part of the code in your question.

Comment: Well not exactly.. I got the code she wanted correctly.. what she wanted was just to have it print the result.. I decided to do this on my own and just try to add so that it prints out "Your BMI Is"  then the result..    So this isnt something she did.. its something I did on my own by trying to add something extra she didnt ask for to the program just to try to further my knowledge..